# How to automatically mass renaming by deleting character in column in pyspark

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

When I type `spark_df.columns` the output is

```
['id',
 'voc_yield_sum_l1.0',
 ...
 'voc_yield_sum_l6.0',
 'sms_yield_sum_l1.0',
 ...
 'sms_yield_sum_l61.0',
 'data_yield_sum_l1.0',
 ...
 'data_yield_sum_l61.0']
```

I want to delete all `.0` in whole dataframe. How suppose to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple split column names by dot `.` and take the first value then use  `selectExpr` with the original columns enclosed in backticks

```
spark_df = spark_df.selectExpr(*["`{0}` as {1}".format(col, col.split('.')[0]) for col in spark_df.columns])
```